# Long field as foreign key in JPA entities, with on-cascade Delete

Tags: java, hibernate, jpa

I'm having issues with defining a foreign key field within an entity. One specific thing that I can't find an answer to, is how to define such field but as a Long type, and not as that target entity type, and also set it up as ON DELETE CASCADE.

E.g.

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "user")
public class UserEntity {
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    private Long id;
}
```

and

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "address")
public class AddressEntity {
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    private Long id;

    @JoinColumn(
       table = "user",
       name = "user_id",
       referencedColumnName = "id")
    private Long userId;
}
```

This example works fine, but now one can't easily define this DELETE ON CASCADE for the userId field i.e. Address entity.

Answer (score 3):

> One specific thing that I can't find an answer to, is how to define
> such field but as a Long type, and not as that target entity type, and
> also set it up as ON DELETE CASCADE.

It stands to reason that you cannot find an answer, because JPA does not provide one.  If you want JPA to manage relationships between entities, then you must define those relationships in the JPA way, with entities holding references to other entity objects and declaring appropriate relationship annotations.* And if you want cascading deletes in your persistence context then you definitely do want them to be managed / recognized by JPA, for any other kind of approach is likely to create problems involving the context falling out of sync with the underlying data store.

It's unclear what problem you are trying to solve by avoiding JPA-style relationship management, but I'm inclined to think that there must be a better way.  For example, if you want to avoid requiring the persistence context to load the associated `UserEntity` whenever an `AddressEntity` is loaded, then you would define the relationship with a lazy fetch strategy:

```
@Entity
public class AddressEntity {
    // ...

    @OneToOne(optional = true, fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
    private UserEntity user;
}

@Entity
public class UserEntity {

    // ...

    @OneToOne(optional = true, fetch = FetchType.LAZY, cascade = CascadeType.ALL,
            mappedBy = user)
    AddressType address;
}
```

(Do note, however, that `FetchType.LAZY` is a hint, not a constraint.  The context might sometimes still load the user together with its address if that's convenient.)

If you want to get the associated user id from an address, then the best way to do so is to read it from the user:

```
    // ...

    public Long getUserId() {
        return (user == null) ? null : user.getId();
    }
```

That does require the `UserEntity` to define an accessible `getId()` method, but since you are using JPA field-based access, you do not need also to provide a setter, and you may give the method default access.  Or you could just declare `UserEntity.id` such that it is directly accessible by `AddressEntity`.

On the other hand, if you want to provide for the user ID to be accessible without loading the user entity then instead of a method such as the above `getUserId()`, in addition to the relationship field you could define a persistent, **read-only** `AddressEntity.userId` field, mapped to the appropriate column.  It must be read-only because the value of the id in the underlying data store will necessarily be managed via the entity relationship, so it cannot also be managed via this separate field.  For example:

```
@Entity
public class AddressEntity {
    // ...

    @OneToOne(optional = true, fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
    private UserEntity user;

    @Column(name = "user_id", insertable = false, updatable = false, nullable = true)
    public Long userId;
}
```

**This is a brittle approach, and I do not recommend it.**  It will be prone to problems with the `userId` field falling out of sync with the `user` entity.  That may be bearable for the usage you have in mind, but this sort of weirdness is fertile ground for future bugs.

---

*Side note: as far as I know or can determine, JPA does not define semantics for a `@JoinColumn` annotation on a non-relationship field such as in your original code.  That doesn't mean that your particular persistence provider can't interpret it in a way that you characterize as "works fine", but at minimum you are on thin ice with that.

Comment: One of the reasons I'd like to avoid this is that when you work a lot of crud on such entities, with Dto classes exposed to an API, you have to deal with persistence of these relations e.g. on update, on create etc. This always ends up with a mess imo, where I have to ensure e.g. UserEntity user is set correctly, will be converted to json and vice versa.

Comment: Another one is just converting to json and vice versa - I'd like to keep the json I have to send and receive over the network minimal. With a UserEntity field,  I'm being forced to have a similar AddresDto with e.g. a UserDto field - and this possibly adds a lot to the json size transfered - a long id field would make this much simpler. If I still want only a long id field in my dto classes, I have to handle the persistence manually on each e.g update iinm. Any tips on how to avoid these issues? And thanks!

Comment: Well yes, @eja, you do have to deal with persisting the relationships on create, update, *etc*. (where *etc*. includes deletion), especially on the owning side of one-to-(one / many) relationships.  But to the extent that you don't want that to include cascading persistence operations to related entities, the proper way to control it is with the `cascade` properties of the JPA relationship annotations.

Comment: As for serializing to JSON, I don't see anything inherently preventing you from using a particular JSON representation either way.